# ATL DoModal() raises an assertion

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I am currently trying to create a modal dialog in my application, like this:

```
RedditRefresherLoginDialog loginDialog;
loginDialog.DoModal();
```

However, as soon as my code reached the DoModal(), I always get an Assertion:

```
Debug assertion failed:
atlwin.h
Line: 3191
Expression: 0
```

My Dialog class looks like this:

```
class RedditRefresherLoginDialog : public CDialogImpl<RedditRefresherLoginDialog>, public CWinDataExchange<RedditRefresherLoginDialog>
{
public:

    RedditRefresherLoginDialog();
    ~RedditRefresherLoginDialog();

    enum { IDD = IDD_REDDITREFRESHERLOGINDIALOG };

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(RedditRefresherLoginDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE, OnClose)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInit)

        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER_EX(IDC_EXIT, OnExitButtonClick)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnClose(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);
    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);
    LRESULT OnInit(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled);

private:

    void OnExitButtonClick(UINT uCode, int nCtrlID, HWND hwndCtrl);
};
```

The assert is caused in the atlwin.h, ~CWindowImplRoot() deconstructor.

```
    if(m_hWnd != NULL)  // should be cleared in WindowProc
    {
        ATLTRACE(atlTraceWindowing, 0, _T("ERROR - Object deleted before window was destroyed\n"));
        ATLASSERT(FALSE);
    }
```

Due to the assert being hit in CWindowImpl, I tried to add inheritance from `public CWindowImpl<RedditRefresherLoginDialog>` and remove the CDialogImpl instead, but then, DoModal doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show the code to `OnExitButtonClick`.  My psychic powers suggest you aren't calling EndDialog...

Comment: DestroyWindow(); is all I call over there. That might actually be wrong considering its a modal. I'll try yours for a second

Comment: Don't call DestroyWindow .  Call EndDialog.

Comment: Incomplete code here - too much to guess. And you need to post full call stack and the point of assertion failure.

Comment: @selbie your answer was indeed correct. thanks